# Firebase remote config not updating and using older value+ Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, updates, firebase-remote-config

When we have a higher version available on the play store. This feature redirects users to the app store to install updates. But it is not working on a few devices. The user still using the older version. If the user clears the storage then an alert is displayed. We can not ask our users to clear storage. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    try {
      versionCheck(context);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
   }


versionCheck(context) async {
        //Get Current installed version of app
        final PackageInfo info = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
        double currentVersion =
            double.parse(info.version.trim().replaceAll(".", ""));
    
        //Get Latest version info from firebase config
        final FirebaseRemoteConfig remoteConfig =
            await FirebaseRemoteConfig.instance;
    
        try {
          // Using default duration to force fetching from remote server.
          await remoteConfig.fetch();
          await remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate();
          remoteConfig.getString('force_update_current_version');
          double newVersion = double.parse(remoteConfig
              .getString('force_update_current_version')
              .trim()
              .replaceAll(".", ""));
          if (newVersion > currentVersion) {
            _showVersionDialog(context);
          }
        } on Exception catch (exception) {
          // Fetch throttled.
          print(exception);
        } catch (exception) {
          print('Unable to fetch remote config. Cached or default values will be '
              'used');
        }
      }
```

When I tried to print the values I am getting the same values new:160.0 current:160.0, clearing the storage of the app from the setting displays the alert.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code in general looks right to me. Though there is a redundant line:

```
remoteConfig.getString('force_update_current_version');
```

But this should be fine.

What I am concerned about is that you replace all your `.` with empty and convert the version to a number. This can result in a bug if there are two versions like:
`1.21.4` vs `1.2.15`. The first one is supposed to be newer, but the code will get `1214 > 1215 is false`

Comment: True but currently I have updated my version from 1.6.0 to 1.7.0, so 170 >160 which is true, and the alert should display.

Comment: Another direction we can consider is the setting of the template. Is there any condition we set in the template that blocks RC from returning a valid value?
I think it would be great if we are able to know what users actually get

Comment: When I tried to print the values I am getting the same values new:160.0 current:160.0, clearing the storage of the app from the setting displays the alert.

Comment: Hi Nibha, do you still get the same issue now? Just realize the RC server is doing something similar to template caching. If the problem is related to caching, it is supposed to be resolved in half day